# Lock screen while drawing - LeafLet

Tags: android, leaflet

I'm working with LeafLet in Android.. **My problem is about drawing tools**. When i want to draw

Polygon,Line or something else, map makes me angry because i just want to click one point on

map for drawing but map is making undesired zoom.

**Second problem is about editing**..   When i want to drag any corner of shape, map is moving instead of corner and i can't edit my shape..

I want to Lock Screen while using Editing, Drawing tools.. How can i do that ?

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);  // GoogleMap has this function for disable move,zoom.. I want to do this with LeafLet
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into documentation. You can do this easly using methods:

```
map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
map.dragging.disable();
```

Whole list is [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-properties).